# PHP localhost PHPMailer email to text fails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Goal: Send text message from emailing (using PHP mailer)

1. Running on a PHP5.3 server hosted on hostyd.org 
   (Working both for sending to actual emails and phone number emails)
2. Locally, Run the code with command line that supports query string (I have windows 7 and php-5.6.9-nts-Win32-VC11-x86) . For example, php-cgi to=123456789@tommail.net msg=helloWorld 
   (Working both for sending to actual emails and phone number emails)
3. However, with localhost(enabled by running php -S 0.0.0.0:80), emails are sent succesfully, but the message is never received from the mobile end?
   (Working only with actual emails like gmails and hotmails, **BUT NOT working** with phone number mails like 123456789@vtext.com or 123456789@tmomail.net)

Have anyone encounter this problem before? How do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending via localhost, it means you are using a local mail server, and if that server is not configured correctly, it's likely that it's able to accept submitted messages (so you don't get any errors), but is unable to send them on to their destination. You need to check your mail server log to see what is happening to them.

Comment: How can I locate my mail server log? My OS is win 7. In addition, why is running the php code on command line works but it's not working when it's hosted by local host and it is running on browser.

Comment: Depends what mail server you use, I don't know where windows keeps its logs. It's common for PHP to have different configs for different SAPIs.

Comment: What is SAPIs? System APIs?

Comment: "Server API", defines how PHP is being run - e.g. as a CLI binary, mod_php apache module, CGI, FPM etc. You can have more than one at a time, and they can have different configs. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

Comment: Cli-server is my local server, which is the one that is not working. Litespeed is my remote host, which is working.